# Can't retrieve user images from local server with django

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble displaying user images in Django, it seems to be mostly working. When the user submits a picture it's successfully storing it 
in the right folder. But I can't display the picture after I've saved it.

Views.py:

```
def upload_pic(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'tracker/upload_pic.html')


def album(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user.extendedprofile.img = request.FILES['uploaded_image']
        user.extendedprofile.save()
        #ExtendedProfile.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id).update(extendedprofile__img=request.FILES['uploaded_image'])

    return render(request, 'tracker/album.html', {"user": user})
```

settings.py (relevant portions)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/viraone/tracker/static'

MEDIA_URL = '/tracker/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tracker/')
```

models.py

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_images/user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class ExtendedProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

forms.py

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #model to store the information about the pictures
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedProfile
        exclude = ()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [url(r'^profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'^login', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^export_info', views.export_info, name='export_info'),
url(r'^product_page', views.product_page, name='product_page'),
url(r'^(?P<object_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_details, name='product_details'),
url(r'^upload_pic', views.upload_pic, name='upload_pic'),
url(r'^album', views.album, name='album'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<p> {{ user.extendedprofile.img }} </p>
<img src="{{ user.extendedprofile.img.url }}"
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of error][image: Screenshot of error 2]

I think it's an issue with `urls.py`, in the debugging menu it's displaying a `404` error for the correct file path, but the image just isn't appearing.

Comment: Can you check and ensure that settings.DEBUG is actually True. Because everything else looks good to me

Comment: It's set to true, in the debugging menu when I click on the error message it tells me  the file that it can't find is of the type "text/html" no idea if that has anything to do with it. I posted my template as well

Comment: Can you post that error too?

Comment: Posted screenshots, I'm trying to load a gif in that example but it doesnt work for any type of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this in `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in template

```
<img src="{{ user.extendedprofile.img.url }}">
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, that's not working either. Unless I'm using it wrong, the directory it shows the error for after I use that django tag shows the `MEDIA_URL` folder like three times before the subdirectory where my images are if that makes sense

Comment: also the docs say to use {% load static %}, {%load get_media_prefix%} isn't recognized. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: okay so it's working now, I removed `{% get_media_prefix %}` but kept `{% load static %}`, that seemed to do the trick